# Why does type aliasing determine whether output is L-value or R-value?

Tags: c++, reference, c++14, lvalue, type-alias

I created a struct with two static functions for testing purposes. The first instance of `f` is called when an `l-value reference` is passed. The second instance is called when an `r-value` is passed:

```
template <typename _Tp>
struct T {
    static constexpr void f(_Tp&) { std::cout <<  "f(T&)  is called!\n"; }
    static constexpr void f(_Tp&&) { std::cout << "f(T&&) is called!\n"; }
};
```

When I was experimenting with `strong types`, I found out the first instance, `T::f(_Tp&)` was called when I attempted to create the strong type implicitly. Why is this? (See following)

```
using T_int = T<int>;

T_int::f(
    typename strong_types::create_strong_type<int, struct tag>(5)()
); // calls f::(T&) (?)

using KG = typename strong_types::create_strong_type<double, struct KG_tag>;
T_int::f(KG(4.2)()); // calls f(T&&)
```

Note that `operator()` returns the value given through the constructor.

Feel free to ask if I need to elaborate.

EDIT: `strong_types` is a namespace. It exists among other things of the alias `create_strong_type`:

```
namespace strong_type {
    template <typename T, typename tag>
    using create_strong_type = Strong_Type<T, tag>;

    ...
}

...

template <typename T, typename tag>
struct Strong_Type {
    constexpr explicit Strong_Type(const T& value) : _value(value) {}
    constexpr explicit Strong_Type(T&& value) : _value(std::move(value)) {}

    constexpr T& operator()() noexcept { return _value; }

private:
    T _value;
};
```

Comment: what is `strong_types` ?

Comment: Sure, but is it a third party library ?

Comment: Oo, I am sorry for my misunderstanding. `strong_types` is a namespace I created myself.

Comment: @LourensDijkstra Then please add the definition of `strong_types::create_strong_type` to the question.

Comment: @LourensDijkstra Then how can we know why you are returning an lvalue instead of an rvalue

Comment: Also unrelated: Identifiers beginning with underscore, followed by uppercase letter are reserved and you are not allowed to use them.

Comment: Your test cases use different underlying types, so you can't conclude that type aliasing is the determining factor.

Comment: Please fix the typos in your edits, the identifiers do not match, e.g. `strong_type` vs `strong_types` and `Strong_Type` and probably `Strong_Type` should be part of the namespace and before `create_strong_type`?. It doesn't compile the way it is even if generously moving around code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is not due to using an alias (`using`), but to the type you pass as first template argument to `create_strong_type`. In one case, it's an `int`, and in the other, a `double`.

Try `T<double>::f(KG(4.2)());` and you will see the argument is passed as lvalue reference (because of the return type of `Strong_Type::operator()`, which is `T&`).